# How to make double headers in memoir? Header with two rulings?

Tags: xetex, header-footer, color, memoir, rules

I want to make a header that will have two rulings...

[image: LayoutGoal]

Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,showframe]{memoir}

\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout


\chapterstyle{bianchi}

\usepackage{blindtext, fontspec}

    \nouppercaseheads
    \makepagestyle{mystyle}
    \setheaderspaces{*}{0.5cm}{*}
    \makeoddhead{mystyle}{\bfseries\sectionmark / \itshape\leftmark}{ \textbf{FooBar~--} \itshape any custom fixed text \\}{\bfseries Page | \itshape\thepage}
    \makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{}{}
    \makepsmarks{mystyle}{%
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}}

    \pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

I do get two lined header but I'm not sure about getting two rules.
Also is there a way to change header,footer to aqua?

Output that I get:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer to the two rules. The following bits of code added/changed to your MWE produce a single rule between the first and second lines of the heading and a rule at the bottom of the heading.

```
...
\setheadfoot{60pt}{20pt} % your header is too large
\checkandfixthelayout
...
\makeheadrule{mystyle}{\textwidth}{0.4pt} % rule at the bottom
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{\bfseries\sectionmark / \itshape\leftmark}%
  {\textbf{FooBar---} \itshape any custom fixed text \\[0.5\baselineskip]}%
  {\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt} \bfseries Page | \itshape\thepage
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It's working fine but header is overlapping the text. I have corrected it by playing with margins and increasing it. But you said that my header is too large... Can you guide me as to what's the right way (or values) of setting up margins & header/footer area?

Comment: The `\sectionmark` isn't working... why??

Comment: @YourPalNurav Run your original MWE and memoir will tell you that the space allocated for your header is too small and suggests a value that should work. I have no idea about your `\sectionmark`, make that a new question.